# fastlane cannot find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, fastlane

I'm setting up fastlane for the first time. On running fastlane test, I get an error about com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 not being found.

Here's just a snippet:

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1. [23:40:20]: ▸
>   Searched in the following locations: [23:40:20]: ▸
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>   [23:40:20]: ▸
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar

However, when I build using Android Studio, everything builds smoothly.

What is going on? Why doesn't fastlane work and Android Studio does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `google()` to all your dependency repositories in `build.gradle`.

Android Studio does this automatically but only when you build from the IDE. You can verify if it's working by calling `./gradlew build` from command line.

Comment: Thanks! Adding it to the buildscript repositories did the trick. :)